# Download private module from Github Package Registry via Yarn within a Github Action? Publishing works, but installing is met with '401 Unauthorized'

Tags: github, yarnpkg, github-actions, github-package-registry, github-ci

For various reasons we are stuck using yarn managing our packages so we can't rely on a package-lock.json to use npm with github actions.

We cannot get Yarn to authenticate as part of a github action.
We've got our repo npmrc configured as:

```
@COMPANY:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

And we're using [this action for yarn.](https://github.com/Borales/actions-yarn)

Here's a basic setup where we're just trying to install the modules -- nothing more.

```
name: CI
on: [push]
jobs:
  build:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v1
      - uses: borales/actions-yarn@v2.1.0
        with:
          auth-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          registry-url: "https://npm.pkg.github.com"
          scope: tlabs
          cmd: version
        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          NPM_REGISTRY_URL: https://npm.pkg.github.com
      - name: Create NPMRC
        run: |
          echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" > ~/.npmrc
      - name: Install
        run: |
           yarn install --verbose
```

By default, this action will try to run install so to bypass that I provided a basic command there 'version' so it just displays the yarn version and nothing more.

Running yarn install will work for all other packages but when it gets to our private modules, it will try to get them from the right registry (github) but will be hit with a 401.

Full error:

```
verbose 7.614802156 Error: https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@tlabs/utils/1.0.1/afe9eaa6f9565f95c31563cbecfe617d7970f44077302cbe9ca8ee3223550469: Request failed "401 Unauthorized"
    at ResponseError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:696:66)
    at new ResponseError (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:802:124)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:66996:16)
    at Request.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at Request.module.exports.Request.onRequestResponse (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:141441:10)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:583:27)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:115:17)
    at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:456:22)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://npm.pkg.github.com/download/@tlabs/utils/1.0.1/afe9eaa6f9565f95c31563cbecfe617d7970f44077302cbe9ca8ee3223550469: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".
```

Comment: The default `GITHUB_TOKEN` is only scoped for the current repository. Have you tried using a `read:packages` and `repo` scoped [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN`?

Comment: Ah. Is there a way to change that or am I just stuck with using a PAT for all of my actions?

Comment: @peterevans aaah, it works with the PAT -- I guess I'll just be happy that it does and move on. If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution.

Comment: There is no alternative as far as I know. It's a deliberate limitation of `GITHUB_TOKEN` that it's only scoped to the current repository.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default `GITHUB_TOKEN` is only scoped for the current repository. You cannot use it to access packages in another repository. Use a `read:packages` and `repo` scoped [Personal Access Token](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

Comment: I'm using my PAT with the mentioned permissions only but still getting the 401 error in GitHub actions.

Comment: Also using my PAT and still getting 401 errors in Github actions. Created a new more in-depth issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64124831/github-actions-401-unauthorized-when-installing-a-github-package-with-npm-or-ya

Answer (score 4):

I'm create a file .npmrc and .yarnrc.
Type:

```
name: Test

on: push
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [12.x]

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Node ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      - name: Create NPMRC
        run: |
            echo "//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=${{ secrets.PACKAGES_TOKEN }}" >> ~/.npmrc
            echo "@you-scope:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com" >> ~/.npmrc
            echo 'registry "https://registry.yarnpkg.com"' >> ~/.yarnrc
      - run: yarn install
```

Replace @you-scope for you user of github or of your org in github in **LowerCase**.
Create a PACKAGES_TOKEN screte for this repository.

Answer (score 0):

Have a .npmrc file in root of your project.

Content of .npmrc:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/
@{scope}:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=********** (Token generated from github)
```

`@{scope}` is your organization-name or your username. It is case-sensitive.
Also, to access both private and public packages in github registry, you need to have a token.

Reference: [You need an access token to publish, install, and delete packages.](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-npm-registry#authenticating-to-github-packages)